# Experiencing ServerException in .NET C# MVC 3 when querying SharePoint 2010 list with CAML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sharepoint-2010, caml

I am attempting to fetch a single item from a SharePoint 2010 list. I am using .NET C# MVC 3 framework.

I am receiving the runtime error "ServerException, Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904" from the ExecuteQuery() method in the following block of code.

```
 ClientContext spContext = new ClientContext(Settings.Default.SharePointSite + Settings.Default.SharePointWeb);
spContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("[REMOVED]", "[REMOVED]", "[REMOVED]");
var list = spContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ExampleList");

var camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UniqueId'/>" +
    "<Value Type='Lookup'>" + id.ToString() + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

var items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

spContext.Load(items);
spContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

If an empty CAML query is passed, "items" is populated will all elements of the list, so the basic connection is working. Introducing any CAML to .ViewXML has resulted in either the already stated exception or has not affected the resultset of "items" (as in, all items have been returned).

Any help that you can provide is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue, where I was trying to query a list and return all items where a "needle" value was contained in a multi-select lookup "haystack":

```
<Where>
  <Contains><FieldRef Name='Environments' /><Value Type='Lookup'>DV</Value></Contains>
</Where>
```

Originally I had the value element's Type attribute as "Text" (which is also the default if no Type is specified), and was getting the "Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))" error.

Then I added the correct Type attribute, and mistakenly added the LookupId attribute to the FieldRef element, which gave me zero results but no error.

The reason it turns out is pretty sensible, and I found described on http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list . Basically, by specifying Type='Lookup', you're evaluating against the display value of the lookup field, but going one step past and saying LookupId='TRUE' on the other element means "evaluate on the foreign item ID, rather than the display value".

So if you're using CAML to query a lookup field, the value should always be of type 'Lookup', but whether or not you use LookupId will depend on whether you want to compare the key or value of the lookup.

Comment: Interesting tidbit, but I'm not sure that it gets us any closer to a solution with this particular problem. We're simply trying to fetch a single row from the database based on matching an ID field, which, in this case, is not linked to a foreign ID.

Comment: Indeed, it's a corollary not a solution. But the reason I felt it was appropriate is the exception being thrown, which for me meant I was defining my field type wrong. If you're not using a foreign ID, why are you specifying Type='Lookup'? If it is a numeric ID, why aren't you specifying LookupId='TRUE'?

Comment: I can't find the original source, but somewhere I read that ID fields, and it may have been GUID-specific fields, are supposed to be of type "Lookup". It sounds like the default "Text" would be more appropriate. Is that what you are thinking?

Comment: Well, what is "UniqueId" in your list/library? If you're just looking for the auto-generated ID integer (which is used in the URL ala ?id= ), I believe that field name is just "Id", and the value is type "Number" or "Integer". I'm still in SP2007 though, so it might have changed, but AFAIK "Lookup" should only be used for custom columns of type Lookup, and I think Person/Group as well

Comment: @Dave: This might not have helped out the OP but it sure saved me from hours of pulling out my hair. If there was a way to upvote you more times, I would do it in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<FieldRef Name="UniqueId" LookupId="TRUE"/><Value Type="Lookup">
```

instead of

```
<FieldRef Name='UniqueId'/><Value Type='Lookup'>
```

and yeah, caml is case sensitive

Comment: Thanks for your response, Ken. I gave this a try and am now getting 0 results back. So, adding the LookupId parameter did make a difference (previously I was receiving all items), but something still isn't right.